# Could the disciples not drive out the demon because of lack of faith or because of lack of fasting and prayer

Tags: matthew, mark

Matthew 17:20 says it is because they had so little faith:

> Then the disciples came to Jesus in private and asked, “Why couldn’t we drive it out?” 20 He replied, “Because you have so little faith.

But then Matthew 17:21 says

> He replied, “This kind can come out only by prayer

Mark 9:29 says the same as the above. So what is the reason the disciples couldn't drive out the demon, a lack of faith or lack of prayer?

Answer (score 1):

NIV Mark 9:

> 28 After Jesus had gone indoors, his disciples asked him privately, “Why couldn’t we drive it out?”
>
> 29 He replied, “This kind can come out only by **prayer**.”

NASB 1995 Matthew 17:

> 19 Then the disciples came to Jesus privately and said, “Why could we not drive it out?” 20And He said to them, “Because of the **littleness of your faith**; for truly I say to you, if you have faith the size of a mustard seed, you will say to this mountain, ‘Move from here to there,’ and it will move; and nothing will be impossible to you. 21[“But this kind does not go out except by **prayer and fasting**.”]

Could the disciples not drive out the demon because of lack of faith or because of lack of fasting and prayer?

Yes, all of the above.